# Customize section in lyx

Tags: lyx-layouts

I am writing in lyx and inserted a new section. i wonder how could i align the section header to the center rather than to the left. I put

`\usepackage{titlesec}`

`\titleformat{\section}{\centering}`

in the preamble but it does not work. Any comments would be appeciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is `\titleformat*{\section}{\centering}` (with the `*`!!)

Or, also `\titleformat{...}[...]{....}{...}{...}{...}[...]` where each `{...}` is a mandatory argument. It cannot work only with two arguments, need at least five., e.g.: some like ...

```
\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{\thetitle.\quad}{1em}{1em}
```

See the manual (run `texdoc titlesec`, page 4) for detailed explanations about the argument-s of both command versions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works. I also try to get the section header to be bold. I read the document for titlesec. I am not sure if I find any solution from there. Do you have any suggestions? Many Thanks

Comment: @Sdeng You can add  some `\large\bfseries`  after `\centering` in the format arguments.